# extract the shortest and first encounter match between two strings in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I want the function to return the string that follows the below condition.

1. after "def"
2. in the parentheses right before the first %ile after "def"

So the desirable output is "4", not "5". So far, I was able to extract "2)(3)(4". If I change the function to str_extract_all, the output became "2)(3)(4" and "5" . I couldn't figure out how to fix this problem. Thanks!

```
x <- "abc(0)(1)%ile, def(2)(3)(4)%ile(5)%ile"

string.after.match <- str_match(string = x,     
                                pattern = "(?<=def)(.*)")[1, 1]

parentheses.value <- str_extract(string.after.match,         # get value in ()
                                 "(?<=\\()(.*?)(?=\\)\\%ile)")

parentheses.value
```

Take the

Comment: `str_extract(x, "(?<=def).*?\\d\\)(?=%ile)")`??

Comment: Thanks! But this seemed to give "(2)(3)(4)" in return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a one liner that will do the trick using `gsub()`

```
gsub(".*def.*(\\d+)\\)%ile.*%ile", "\\1", x, perl = TRUE)
```

Here's an approach that will work with any number of "%ile"s. Based on `str_split()`

```
x <- "abc(0)(1)%ile, def(2)(3)(4)%ile(5)%ile(9)%ile"
x %>% 
  str_split("def", simplify = TRUE) %>% 
  subset(TRUE, 2) %>% 
  str_split("%ile", simplify = TRUE) %>% 
  subset(TRUE, 1) %>% 
  str_replace(".*(\\d+)\\)$", "\\1")
```

Comment: This only works if there are two `ile` cannot work in case there are more than 2 or just 1.

Comment: OK, I'll add a more general. solution now.

Answer (score 2):

```
 sub(".*?def.*?(\\d)\\)%ile.*", "\\1", x)
[1] "4"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```r
x <- "abc(0)(1)%ile, def(2)(3)(4)%ile(5)%ile"
library(stringr)
result <- str_match(x, "\\bdef(?:\\((\\d+)\\))+%ile")
result[,2]
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/lFnbgg) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YBxCtZ/1).

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `def` - a `def` string
- `(?:\((\d+)\))+` - zero or more occurrences of `(` + one or more digits (captured into Group 1) + `)` and the last one captured is saved in Group 1
- `%ile` - an `%ile` string.